# Closing a modal window launched from App.xaml triggers WindowClosing event

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF application, where as part of the startup, I need to show a modal window to get some informatin from the user. 
I create and show the window from inside App.xaml.cs_ApplicationStartup.
In the window's ok button, I call the Close() method.
Once the information is retrieved, I want to show the main application window.
However, the main application window immediately received a WindowClosing event and terminates.
App.xaml code:

```
private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.Default.AskForLoginCredentials)
    {
        var loginWindow = new LoginCredentialsWindow();
        bool? retVal = loginWindow.ShowDialog();
        if (retVal.HasValue && retVal.Value)
        {
            string un = loginWindow.UserName;
            string pw = loginWindow.Password;
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Info("Credential request prompt was refused. Exiting Application.");
            return;
        }
    }

    MainAppWindow window = new MainAppWindow();
    window.Show();
}
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [Application.ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) property

The default is `OnLastWindowClose`, which means the application will shut down when the last window closes. The other two options are `OnMainWindowClose` and `OnExplicitShutdown`

I typically use `OnExplicitShutdown`, which means [Shutdown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdown.aspx) needs to be called for the application to exit